# Passing more than one model to the view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: view, model

I need to pass two models in the same view, however some elements have the same name.

I have two models `Employee` and `HolidayRequestForm` and I need to use both of these in the one view which will be a details page for each Employee.

Here is my `Employee`:

```
public partial class Employee
{ 
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string EmailID { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
    public int ShiftID { get; set; }
    public int AreaID { get; set; }
    public int DisciplineID { get; set; }
    public int SiteID { get; set; }
    public int ALCategory { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> HoursTaken { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AwardedLeave { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TotalHoursThisYear { get; set; }
    public int HoursCarriedForward { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> EntitlementRemainingThisYear { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }

   }
```

Here is my `HolidayRequestForm`:

```
public partial class HolidayRequestForm
{
    public int RequestID { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime FinishDate { get; set; }
    public int HoursTaken { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public int YearCreated { get; set; }
    public int MonthCreated { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DayCreated { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> YearOfHoliday { get; set; }

}
```

I have tried Creating a separate model that contains all elements to use in the view but I'm not sure how to differentiate elements with the same name eg. Comments Is it even possible to do so?

I would like to use both these models in my view as I'd like to create an Employee Profile page, with their info on the top displaying information about their profile and then holidays they have requested using the holidayrequestform in a table on the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a `ViewModel` which will contain both `Employee` and `HolidayRequestForm`  as follows and then pass the `ViewModel` to the view:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public Employee Employee {get; set;}

    public HolidayRequestForm HolidayRequestForm {get; set;}
}
```

Then in your action method:

```
public ActionResult EmployeeDetails(int id)
{
     Employee employee =  _dbContext.Employees.FirstOrDefault(emp => emp.EmployeeID == id);
     HolidayRequestForm holidayRequestForm =  _dbContext.HolidayRequestForms.FirstOrDefault(hrf => hrf.EmployeeID == id);

     EmployeeViewModel employeeViewModel = new EmployeeViewModel()
     {
        Employee = employee,
        HolidayRequestForm  = holidayRequestForm
     }

     return View(employeeViewModel);
}
```

Then in the view, access the model properties as follows:

```
@model EmployeeViewModel

<p>Full Name: @Model.Employee.FullName</p>
```

Comment: How Should I bind the model to the view? Would it be something like `@model LotusWorksHT.Models.EmployeeViewModel` LotusWorksHT being the name of the project.

Comment: Yes! It should be fully qualified namespace! If your `EmployeeViewModel` reside in the `Models` folder of `LotusWorksHT` project then it should be `@model LotusWorksHT.Models.EmployeeViewModel` as you said.

Comment: hmm I get a null exception when I use `Full Name: @Model.Employee.FullName`. but then I tried  `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Employee.FullName)` and no data showed up. I suspect the data is not being passed into the  view?? or did it mess up with the model? Thanks for all the help, it has got me started anyways.

Comment: @Conor8630 that means your `Employee` in the `EmployeeViewModel ` is null! Debug in the method to ensure is it pulling `Employee` data from the database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186483/discussion-between-conor8630-and-tanvirarjel).